# Locked-down XP session on thin client misplaces Quick Launch bar

Tags: windows-xp, citrix, windows, xenapp

Users are working from thin clients (Wyse) on a Microsoft network. They work with XP. One of the users has his Quick Launch bar placed to the right bottom with one icon visible, while all others have it in the default spot, left bottom.
I deleted the profile in the TSProfile directory so he would start with a fresh profile, that didn't work. The profiles are very locked down, there is very little users can change and specifically to this problem not the taskbar (icons nor location). That also means he cannot change it to the right side.
What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% but is this a new user? It could be a problem with the default user profile, maybe worth a look even if it is a stab in the dark!
It may also be worth granting the user elevated priviledges to move the Quick Launch bar!

Sorry if its not an acceptable answer, just and idea!

Comment: This environment is in migration to thin clients, we got a lot of new clients weekly. It's a move to a new domain and subnet structure, not in-place.

No new clients after or before him have experienced this. Elevated privileges was a good idea which I had completely overlooked but alas it didn't solve the problem.

It was an acceptable answer but, as most ansers go until the last that comes up, it didn't solve it :-)

Comment: Hi Erwin, unless your problem is solved it isnt an acceptable answer! I will have a think and see if i can come up with anything else.

Comment: Don't you love how fast things move in IT? This client wanted to slow down the project, so last in first out and I;m working at a new client already. So I'm off this problem.

Comment: excellent! Customers are fun! very trying but fun!